# Comments for multiple parent objects

Tags: database, database-design, web-applications, yii

I'm learning to build web-apps in the Yii PHP framework, but I think my question applies to web-applications in general.

I want to know how to structure database tables for comments that relate to different types of parent objects, i.e- photos or posts.

Photos and Posts are inherently different and wouldn't sit in the same table. However the comments on these objects are in most cases of identical format.

My question is two fold, is it possible to put comments for multiple parent objects into the same table? [Seems to me to be the natural solution, but I'm not sure how to take care of this with foreign/primary keys etc. I think it also needs a key to point towards the type of parent object...?]

Second, if it is possible to put these comments into the same table, is it efficient to do so, is it more efficient to have a comment table for every parent object?

Thanks in advance, hope it's an interesting enough topic for someone.

Cheers,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other option is to have a post table to which all posts relate (regardless of type). So whether it's a photo or a normal post, it will have a records created for it in this table.

Depending on the type of content, you could store both photos and normal posts in this table (with optional fields for each, eg: photo, photo_type, post_content could be optional depending on what type is being created (this would be a good opportunity to learn about Yii model validation scenarios).

So you post table would look something like:

- id
- post_content
- photo
- photo_type
- etc...

If you choose not to store both in the same table, you could have 1 table for photos and 1 for posts which relate back to a post_id

That way, you could have a single comment table (which regardless is the correct route) which relate to a post_id.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I understood your proposed methods. I gather from what you're saying that having multiple comment tables is certainly not the conventional approach, am I correct? Then, in a nutshell, you can either skilfully put your content into one table and map the comments to it. Or have a third table that takes care of the mapping from multiple content types to comments. Is this the gist of it? Are either of these methods likely to be more efficient at all, or is there little difference?

Comment: No problem :) Yes, that's what I'm suggesting. The main thing is that you definitely only need one comment table. How you handle the posts is up to you, but the more conventional way would be to have a single table that handles all types, but this obviously depends on the complexity of your data structure. In terms of efficiency, they are much the same, but your code will be easier to maintain if you have a single post table

Comment: And, what you're saying about different post types in one table is really interesting, cheers.

Comment: No problem and good luck. An interesting example of this type of usage is wordpress, which uses very few database tables in a highly flexible way. Google "wordpress database schema" and you will see some great examples of table "type" flexibility. All the best :)

Answer (score 1):

I would model Comment as a table on it's own.   The Comment table would have a columns for PhotoId and PostId.  These are foreign keys that allow nulls.  Then a database check constraint would ensure that exactly one of PhotoId and PostId is null.  i.e. each comment is attached to exactly one parent.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest 3 table structure

Table: [Entity_Types] (List all object titles such as photos, posts)
Example: 
PK:1001, "Photos"

Table: [Photos]
Example:
PK:2001, "My 1st Photo Title"
PK:2002, "My 2nd Photo Title"

Table: [Comments] 
Examples:
PK:3001, "My 1st Comment for My 1st Photo", FK:1001, FK:2001
PK:3002, "My 2nd Comment for My 1st Photo", FK:1001, FK:2001
PK:3003, "My 1st Comment for My 2nd Photo", FK:1001, FK:2002